# viewPager and pageAdapter relationship

Tags: android, android-viewpager, adapter

Good day,i'm learning android development and would like to know as much possible in as much possible detail for better coding purposes, could some one explain in greater detail the relationship between view-Pager and page-Adapter/Adapter?
I'm asking this here because i would like to hear it from a professional who could actually explain it in depth.

Comment: You can use google for this question. Maybe this link can help you https://inducesmile.com/android/understanding-android-viewpager-and-custom-pageradapter/

Comment: @Aytek not really, i want to know how it works under the hood.

Comment: viewPager just an transaction if you need to switch/change between FragmentActivity.... and if pageAdapter is an manipulation of data which is the data will you set in layout..

Answer (score 0):

PageAdapter is responsible for creating Views.

ViewPager is a component that scrolls over views.

The ViewPager requests the PageAdapter for Views for each position.